# Cocoa WebView SWF

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I am trying to load an SWF inside a WebView in my cococa app, it works fine when I load an HTML which references the SWF. But i'd like do load the flash file alone, with no HTML. Is that possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer for that. It is not quite a fix, but it can get my app working for now.
Every time swf is loaded it make a call to debugger and XCode stops.

According to this [post](http://www.stinkbot.com/blog/archives/69), I should disable the option "Stop on debugger" at run menu in XCode.
Now my project is up and running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It's broken in currently-released WebKit (even on Snow Leopard), but last I checked, it was fixed in WebKit nightlies, so it'll work again someday.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still can't display a SWF in a WebView. I've downloaded the latest nightly and the problem still the same.